# Проблема с переменной в $_POST при добавлении в корзину woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, ajax, woocommerce

При помощи ajax передаю value в functions.php

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
 $('body').on('submit', '[data-name=add_to_cart]', function(e) {
    var regular = 2;
    
    $.ajax({
        url: '<?php echo admin_url('admin-ajax.php') ?>',
        type: 'POST',
        data: 'action=add_custom_price&regular='+regular, 
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function( response ) { 
            alert( response );
        }
    });
  });
});
```

в functions.php обработчик

```
add_action ('wp_ajax_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price'); 
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price'); 
add_action ('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price');
 
function add_custom_price( $cart_object ) { 
    global $woocommerce;
    //для проверки в $_REQUEST['regular'] передается 2
    $custom_price = json_decode($_REQUEST['regular']); 
    
    $prdct = wc_get_product('994');
    
    $s = $prdct->sale_price;
    $p = $prdct->regular_price; 
    
    if($custom_price == 2){
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) { 
            if($value['data']->get_id() == 994){
                $value['data']->set_price($s);
            }
        }
    }else{
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) { 
            if($value['data']->get_id() == 994){
                $value['data']->set_price($p);
            }
        }
    }
    echo $custom_price;        
    }
```

и здесь я не могу понять в чем проблема, `$custom_price` возвращает 2, а в set_price попадает переменная $p.
Ну а если поставить `if($custom_price == 0)` то в set_price попадает $s.
Что я делаю не так?

Answer (score 0):

Тут не в $_POST проблема. Если при вызове хука 'woocommerce_before_calculate_totals' передается объект корзины, то при вызове ajax - объект корзины не передается

снимите хук

add_action ('woocommerce_before_calculate_totals', 'add_custom_price'); - он будет вызываться не только в ajax, а при каждом пересчете

Попробуйте так

```
add_action ('wp_ajax_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price'); 
add_action ('wp_ajax_nopriv_add_custom_price', 'add_custom_price'); 

function add_custom_price( $cart_object = false ) { 
    global $woocommerce;

    if (!$cart_object) {
        $cart_object = WC()->cart;
    }

    //для проверки в $_REQUEST['regular'] передается 2
    $custom_price = json_decode($_REQUEST['regular']); 
    
    $prdct = wc_get_product('994');
    
    $s = $prdct->sale_price;
    $p = $prdct->regular_price; 
    
    if($custom_price == 2){
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) { 
            if($value['data']->get_id() == 994){
                $value['data']->set_price($s);
            }
        }
    }else{
        foreach ( $cart_object->cart_contents as $key => $value ) { 
            if($value['data']->get_id() == 994){
                $value['data']->set_price($p);
            }
        }
    }
    echo $custom_price;        
}
```

Comment: от хука я не могу избавится, ради него все и затевалось, решил сделать через `WC()->session->set('get_variant',$custom_price)`